# Define signal for "Simulate arbitrary signal" from database

Tags: labview, graphical-programming

I managed to make some arbitrary signals manually, but I want to define them in a database and at the define signal part from the Arbitrary signal properties I would like to take the values from a DB.

I have never worked with DB in Labview, and I'm a labview noob. Do you know some tutorials or schemas for what I'm trying to do? Thanks.

Comment: The LabView database kit is >$1000... do you already have a DB set up to use?  Why a database and not something else?  http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209060

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://performancemicrowave.com/sql_LV.html

http://www.jeffreytravis.com/lost/labsql.html

Free alternatives to NI's DB kit.  Without knowing more about your DB, whether it is already set up or not, what type of DB it is, etc, it's hard to provide more help than this.